# Getting content-type in .ashx from uploadify

Tags: asp.net, uploadify, ashx

I able to upload my file through uploadify + `.ashx`, but the problem is I always get `ContentType = application/octet-stream`

Lets say I upload an image, I expected to return me `"image/pjpeg"`, but it always return `"application/octet-stream"` no matter what file I uploaded.

Please advice how to get the correct contentType in .ashx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that most probably content type is getting set by browser. Regardless, different browsers may set different content type for different files - and they may fall back to generic content type such as "application/octet-stream" for any binary file (pdf, zip, doc, xls). Its possible that one browser would report docx as "application/vnd.openxmlformats" while other as ""application/x-zip-compressed" and yet another as "application/octet-stream". And yet all of them are correct, because docx are binary file and are compressed (zip) files.

In short, my suggestion is that you should not rely on the content type sent by client (beyond certain extent such as deciding whether its text, html or binary etc) and rather use server side sniffing logic to determine type of file content. Simple sniffing can be based on file extension while more robust implementation will loot at actual file contents where typically first few bytes of file indicate the file type.

Comment: @VinaryC Do u have any rules for defining content-type base on file extension ? according your answer I should define customize right ?

Comment: @kst, thats correct - I am saying that you should write your own logic on server to decide the file content type. This is assuming that you were going to using content type header to decide what to do with the file type. Extension base sniffing means creating a dictionary - i.e. .gif means image/gif, .pdf means application/pdf etc